# crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated VM10:6747

Tags: mongodb, express, visual-studio-code, debugging

Hello I am super new to web development, currently doing the udemy bootcamp. I was working on my app and everything was fine but suddenly my browser stopped rendering and I got this error:

VM10:6747 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

Got the error even though it shows in my terminal that the database is connected and working. I googled and youtubed this problem but none of the solutions online seem to work. I am using VSC and I went ahead and deleted the launch.json file but that didnt work either. Any other suggestions would really be appreciated. Is there anything within my code that can produce this error? Here is my app.js in case I am missing something.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ejsMate = require('ejs-mate'); //this is an engine use to parse ejs
const session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const ExpressError = require('./utils/ExpressError');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');

//requiring routes
const campgrounds = require('./routes/campgrounds');
const reviews = require('./routes/reviews');


mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/yelp-camp', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Database connected")
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("Database not connected")
        console.log(err)
    });

const app = express();

app.engine('ejs', ejsMate); //here we are telling express to use the engine we selected instead of the default one
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));


app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //to help us parse the req.body
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(flash);

const sessionConfig = {
    secret: 'thisshouldbeabettersecret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true, //this is a security item
        expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, //date.now is in miliseconds. the numbers after are a multiplication = to a week
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    }
}
app.use(session(sessionConfig));


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    next();
});

app.use('/campgrounds', campgrounds);
app.use('/campgrounds/:id/reviews', reviews);

app.get('/app', (req, res) => {
    // res.send('hello! working on your request')
    res.render('home')
})


// HOME PAGE
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('HOMEPAGE!');
})


//ERROR MIDDLEWARE
app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
    next(new ExpressError('Page not found', 404))
}) //this selects all and if nothing else wrongs this will.

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    const { statusCode = 500 } = err; //here we are deconstructing our expresserror and then sending the message 
    if (!err.message) err.message = 'Oh no, Something Went Wrong';
    res.status(statusCode).render('error', { err })
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Serving in port 3000")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! Found the error.

Had:

```js
app.use(flash)
```

Instead of:

```js
app.use(flash())
```